# remove the parent element by clicking on a button inside it "more than once" using VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a ul full of lis every li contains more than one element like this

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>
        <p>some text </p>
        <button>delete</button>
     <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>some other text </p>
        <button>delete</button>
     <div>
     </li>

</ul>
```

now I wanna allow the user to delete any single li by pressing on the button within the li without deleting the rest of them
I have tried many solutions best thing I got to was deleting only the first element, nothing more
please help

that's my JS code for the delete button, the lis are dynamically added items and I have pushed them into an array in hope of being able to delete or edit them

```
 deletBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        var target = e.target;
        let itemIndex = 0;
        for (const item of items){
            if (item.index === target.parentNode.parentNode.index){
                items.splice(item.index, 1); 
                items.Children[item.index].remove();
                break;
            }
            itemIndex++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to move up twice (not thrice) in the DOM tree to find the `<li>` ancestor of the `<button>`.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
```

Demo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>
        <p>some text </p>
        <button>delete</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>some other text </p>
        <button>delete</button>
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you it worked, I guess the issue wasn't with the node parent
but with the selector, I used querySelector which selects only the first element, it's easy how one forgets

Comment: @AhmedSarhan Happy to help.